# Symfony 3.4 & PHPUnit 7.0.1 not possible?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

Is it possible to use the newest version of PHPUnit (7.0.1) with Symfony 3.4?
I receive the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\CoverageListener::startTest(PHPUnit\Framework\Test $test) must be compatible with PHPUnit\Framework\TestListener::startTest(PHPUnit\Framework\Test $test): void in /var/www/vhosts/facto/vendor/symfony/phpunit-bridge/CoverageListener.php on line 30

My phpunit-bridge is not compatible with the newest version of PHPUnit.

Answer (score 6):

The codebase for [symfony/phpunit-bridge for 3.4.4](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v3.4.4/CoverageListener.php) and [4.0.4](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v4.0.4/CoverageListener.php) are identical, Both of which extend `PHPUnit\Framework\BaseTestListener`, and was removed in PHPUnit 7.0. 
So the issue would persist in the 3.4 and 4.0 versions of Symfony.

In order to use PHPUnit 7.0 you would need to upgrade to Symfony 4.1. Which supports PHPUnit 5, 6, and 7. Where Symfony 3.4 and 4.0 support PHPUnit 6 when used with PHP 7.0+

---

**UPDATE**

[symfony/phpunit-bridge 3.4.5](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v3.4.5/CoverageListener.php) added support for PHPUnit 7, where [symfony/phpunit-bridge 3.4.7](https://github.com/symfony/phpunit-bridge/blob/v3.4.7/CoverageListener.php)  fixed an issue with autoloading.